# Android menu not firing click

Tags: android, appbar

This is my `onNavigationItemSelected`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
        HomeActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_extrato) {
        //Nothing yet
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_bloqueio) {
        //Nothing yet
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_rede) {
        //Nothing yet
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
        signOut();
        return true;
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

And this is my menu: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7Ek1.jpg

I have a breakpoint in the beginning of the function, and just stop in breakpoint when i click on home button.

EDIT: My menu is not a listview. Here is my menu:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/background"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />
```

And "@menu/activity_home_drawer" is this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home"
        android:title="Home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_extrato"
        android:icon="@drawable/extrato"
        android:title="Extrato" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_bloqueio"
        android:icon="@drawable/bloqueio"
        android:title="Bloqueio" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_rede"
        android:icon="@drawable/rede"
        android:title="Rede Credenciada" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/exit"
        android:title="Logout" />
```

**EDIT 2**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Home:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/act_logout"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title=""
    android:icon="@drawable/blank"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Comment: Have you seen your code that what you have done?? You are opening the same activity which is currently open and that too without animation. How you gonna notice any changes then

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` function and then match the items id with `item.getItemId()`

Hope this helps.

**Update**
I caught you. You are talking about the navigation item. Navigation drawer actually contains the `ListView` and you have to implement `OnItemClickListener` on `ListView` to fetch the item

```
ListView listViewDrawer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_leftdrawer);
listViewDrawer.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
});
```

Comment: Yeah, i'm doing this, but when i click on any button that is not the first(home) dont fire the onOptionsItemSelected function

Comment: Please show the `onCreateOptionsMenu`, are you using any custom layout for menu

Comment: `onOptionsItemSelected` is called when you create menu from `onCreateOptionsMene` and infalate the menu. Please see the updated answer

Comment: Sorry, i'm newbie android, i don't get it yet

Comment: If you are making `NavigationDrawer` then you have some `ListView` in your xml. The menu you shared via link is `ListView` so in order to get the events like `Logout`, `extracto` etc then you have to set `listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {})`. When you will click on `Logout`, this listener will receive the events

Comment: Please post your `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Comment: Please try to add `//Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if(menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
                else menuItem.setChecked(true);` in `onNavigationItemSelected`

Comment: didn't change anything, still the same problem